# Selecting random rows from SQL database and storing for re-use on another page

Tags: php, mysql, random

My problem is, in question.php I wish to select 5 random rows from my database (questions) and then echo these questions as necessary with the associated answers.  I then wish to, on result.php use those same 5 random selections in order to give correct/incorrect answer feedback.  My problem is if I query the database using the same rand query I will get 5 different random questions.  The query I have in question.php is:

```
<?php
    $query="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM dspstuff ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5) T1 ORDER BY id";
?>
```

I then echo the relative 4 options associated with the question in the database:

```
<?php       


    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {                                                                  
    $options = array($row['option1'], $row['option2'], $row['option3'], $row['answer']);                            
    shuffle($options);  


    echo '<p>';                                                                                         
    echo $row['id'] . '.  '; 
    echo $row['question'];
    echo '</p>';

    foreach($options as $option){?>
    <p><input type="radio" name="ID<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $option; ?>"><?php echo $option; ?></p>
    <?php  }
        echo '<br>';                              
        }                           
    ?>
```

This all works correctly with the db connect info saved elsewhere.  I need to know what query to use or possibly utilise session variables to save the random ids selected.  Say I say select rows 1,2,3,4,5 from the db I need to use those rows in results.php, how would I go about achieving this?

EDIT:
If $_SESSION['ID'] is an array with 5 values, (ids), what would be the select query for retrieving each array entry?
ie.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id ='{$_SESSION['ID']}";
```

Comment: You should create one or more hidden fields in your form, being their value the ids of the randomly selected rows. Then retrieve them in result.php

Comment: @gmc This would allow the user to manipulate the answers. He could exchange the ids for something else and answer those questions he already knows the answer to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: That it right. Those should be stored in the db somehow

Comment: all the information is stored within a database already.  I just need a query to retrieve the same IDs from the database a second time on result.php

Answer (score 0):

To prevent [Cross-site-request-forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (that is: relying on the user sending back the correct question IDs he was presented) I recommend (as you correctly stated in the question) to keep track of the questions presented to the user either in `$_SESSION` or in the database (if you have identified the user, i.e. he is logged in).

To do that, you first select your random questions and save their IDs in `$_SESSION`:

```
$_SESSION["questionID_$rowIndex"] = $row["id"];
```

When the user answers the questions, you can retrieve the original IDs by reading `$_SESSION["questionID_0"]` to `$_SESSION["questionID_4"]`.

For that, in both scripts, you need to call `session_start()` in the very beginning.

AFAIK, the session-serializer is also capable of serializing arrays, so you should also be able to do something like this:

```
$_SESSION["questionIDs"] = array();   
foreach($row in $resultset) //pseudo-foreach here
    $_SESSION["questionIDs"][] = $row["id"];
```

and access it by

```
$_SESSION["questionIDs"][0] - $_SESSION["questionIDs"][4]
```

This will give you the IDs you previously presented to the user.

Although i would prefer the database-storage-thing: Save the data in the database, together with either the session-id you can retrieve by calling `php_session_id()` after initializing the session with `session_start()` or the user id if you know it.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SESSION to store your ids.

[Session](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) Variables are kept during requests.

Call session_start(); at the beginning of your script and then you can save the ids like $_SESSION['ID']=...

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM dspstuff WHERE id in (%s)", implode(',', $_SESSION['ID']) );
```

Comment: please see edit, i have saved each row id to a session variable, but need to know how to retrieve them using a query

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. You could for example use the following SQL Syntax: ... where id in (1,2,3,4,5)